# Sql databse backup on remote machine

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, backup

I am trying to take SQL database backup using asp.net c#. It works fine if code and database is on same server, but it does not create database backup if code is on different server and database is on different server.
Please help.

I had given the full permission to folder where the database backup is getting stored.

Comment: Can you share the code which triggers the database backup?

Comment: does your C# code connect to SQL database from other servers?

Comment: What database is it?